# Update OR Delete

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a set of records.

I need to perform an update operation on a column(which is a part of unique constraint), If the update would result in violation of unique constraint, then I don't do the update instead I do a delete.

Is there a simple/cleaner way to do this?

Comment: Why would you do a `delete`?  The `update` will fail anyway.

Comment: Why tell when you can show? :) Please, include tables, example data and whatever you tried (and failed)

Comment: Cleaner way than what? Show us your way and we can help further.

Comment: Read this.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

First delete the rows whose updates would result in a constraint violation, then do the update on the remaining rows.